# How to point to homepage without any controller or action in YII

Tags: php, yii

How do i point to homepage using CHtml?

I tried `CHtml::link('go home',array(''))` but it seems to point to current page.

I want to point to index.php only.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
echo Chtml::link('Go Home', '/');
```

This is tested and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try CHtml::link('/',array(''))

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **Yii::app()->homeUrl**

```
echo  CHtml::link('go home',array(Yii::app()->homeUrl));
```